# Enable page scrolling for jQuery UI Dialogs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, widget

I'm using a [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) widget to open up multiple windows on a webpage. By default, these windows can be moved around - and from the looks of it, jQuery UI leverages the [Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) to accomplish this.

Draggable can allow the item you're dragging to grow the page vertically to follow the item you're dragging (if you set the "scroll" option to true). However, the way that Dialog uses Draggable doesn't enable that feature, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to turn it on.

I've tried the code below with no luck (including trying the 2nd line after the element loaded in case it just didn't take effect on startup):

```
$("#my_div").dialog ();
$("#my_div").parent ().draggable ('option','scroll',true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could chain the `.dialog('widget')` method to retrieve the jQuery object containing the generated wrapper. Then change the draggable `containment` property to `false`:

Here is an example:

```js
$('#dialog').dialog().dialog('widget').draggable('option', 'containment', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Basic jQuery-UI dialog that can be dragged off the screen.</p>
</div>
```